# Java swing Header & Footer background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jpanel, setbackground

[image]Is there any way to set Header and Footer in Java Swing?

Actually I am using theme in my application and I have set fixed background color for all panels. But now the work is to set different background color of Header and Footer panel. Can you give me any suggestion?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you illustrate with a screenshot what you mean by header and footer?

Comment: where's the problem? header/footer.setBackground(....)

Answer (score 1):

Header and Footer are probably just `JPanel`s, so you can do `setBackground(Color.YELLOW)` or such. As you probably have several header and footes (seeing those tabs), you could make a single class:

```
public class HeaderOrFooter extends JPanel {
    private static final Color bg = new Color(0xFFFF66);
    public HeaderOrFooter() {
       setBackground(bg);
    }
}
```

You can even use a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemColor.html (for theming), like `SystemColor.info`.

Comment: how can I set different background color of header and footer??

Comment: Make two classes Header and Footer.